# Python thresholding: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src0.empty() in function 'cv::medianBlur'

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to perform adaptive thresholding on all the images in my zip file. I'm not sure why am I getting the `(-215:Assertion failed) !_src0.empty() in function 'cv::medianBlur'` error.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import cv2
```

Step 1: I uploaded and extracted all the images into `image_file`.

```
file = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/cyc001_reg002.zip"
image_file = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/images"

# Read image arrays from image files
with ZipFile(file, 'r') as z:
    z.extractall(image_file)

for i in os.listdir(image_file):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_file, i))
```

Step 2: I converted the images into 8-bit.

```
img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
```

Step 3: I performed adaptive thresholding.

```
ret, th1 = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
```

Traceback:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/CODEX/main.py", line 26, in <module>
>     img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-q3d_8t8e\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\median_blur.dispatch.cpp:283:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src0.empty() in function
> 'cv::medianBlur'
```

Comment: Can you print the name of img, and check if this image really exists in the folder image_file?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code out. Seems like the adaptive threshold operation can only be made in a grayscale image. When I open an image in rbg I get the same error. But works fine in grayscale images.

Try transforming your image to grayscale. :)

OpenCV has builtin funtions to do this i.e:

When loading the image:

```
gray = cv2.imread('imageName.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

or when alredy loaded:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

This uses a combination of channels that's explained here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html

If you wish to use only one channel of your choosing, try to to this

```
blueChannel  = img[:,:,0]
greenChannel = img[:,:,1]
redChannel   = img[:,:,2]
```

Remember if you use openCV the order of the channels is gbr and not rgb